# Charging six 3.7 V, 9900 mAh lithium-ion batteries in series with a solar panel configuration

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, parallel, charging, series

I am trying to build a system that charges three batteries in series that are 3.7 V each with 9900 mAh each.

I want four solar panels rated at 1 W, 6 V, and 160 mA each to charge the batteries. What configuration of the solar panels should I use so they charge faster and effectively power an Arduino Mega? Parallel or series?

Comment: What physical size are your batteries?

Comment: Three or six cells? Title does not match question body. Assuming three: You need about 13 V to fully charge three of those Li-ion cells in series, so putting the solar panels in parallel won't work. You could put the panels in series and use a MPPT solar 3S battery charger.

Comment: What kind of batteries are these? It will take ages to charge six 3.7V 9900mAh batteries with just 4W (peak) of solar panels.

Comment: This is easily answered ONCE full information is provided. What are the loaded and open circuit voltages of the solar panels. Is 6V Vmp or Voc.  What voltage does your Arduino operate from? You say thress batteries in series BUT this may not be the best choice.